# css color inhertance when the link is inside the text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, styles

The color of text is set to white inside the container, which has text in it. But the link inside the text is not showing up as white instead blue.

I am using material ui styles.

have tried !important tag , still not working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help you, you'll have to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It sounds like there are still CSS values active on the HTML-element you used for the link. Have you tried inspecting the element in the browser to find where the blue color is coming form? If you could provide the code, your question can be answered more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

this problem may have occured because you linked another library that override your css
If this is correct you should link your css after the link of the library

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='library'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='your_css'>
```

or you can do that

```
.container a {
  color: white !important;
}
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

The  [default](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php) css color value of an a tag is not inherit but an internal value, so to change the color of the link you have to specify a css rule for the a tag or use a class

```
a {
   color: white;
}

/* or */

.link {
   color: white;
}
```

```
<div>
some text .... <a class="link" href="">link</a>
</div>
```